# how can I dynamically set the start widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I plan to choose the start widget in my main class dynamically. I want to choose between a login class, an onboarding class and a main menu class.

Since I am new to flutter, I don't know how to implement this properly so that I can check for login before app start and then open the corresponding page.

My main class currently looks like this

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );



  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State {
  ThemeStuff appValueNotifier = ThemeStuff.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: appValueNotifier.theme,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Handball Tippspiel',
            theme: value,
            home: const Login(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            routes: {
              '/login': (context) => const Login(),
              '/register': (context) => const Register(),
              '/home': (context) => const Home(),
              '/onboarding': (context) => const Onboarding(),
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for "deep links".  There's a lot of literature on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are working with firebase. If you want to check for login i.e if a user has signed up or not.

You will use StreamBuilder to listen for AuthChanges.class

```
MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final ThemeStuff appValueNotifier = ThemeStuff.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: appValueNotifier.theme,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Handball Tippspiel',
          theme: value,
          home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Home(); // If the user has authenticated before, take us to the home page
              } else {
                return const Onboard(); // If the user hasn't logged in, proceed to the onboarding screen
              }
            },
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          routes: {
            '/login': (context) => const Login(),
            '/register': (context) => const Register(),
            '/home': (context) => const Home(),
            '/onboarding': (context) => const Onboarding(),
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Another alternative is to use SharedPrefrence to determine if a user has logged in or not.

```
Future<bool> _isFirstLaunch() async {
    final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstLaunch = sharedPreferences
            .getBool('first_launch') ??
        true;
    if (isFirstLaunch)
      sharedPreferences.setBool(
          'first_launch', false);

    return isFirstLaunch;
  }
```